# ¿Cómo verifico si una consulta a una tabla de mysql esta devolviendo una o varias filas?

Tags: php

Estoy utilizando la fetch() API para implementar una consulta a una tabla y en esta consulta quisiera saber cuantas filas (tuplas) me está devolviendo con la finalidad de hacer una condicional para grabar y mostrar los datos obtenidos dentro de un contenedor.

Código en JavaScript:

```
function cargarSimilares() {
   let cod = localStorage.getItem("codPROD");
   let cat = localStorage.getItem("categoria");
   let subcat = localStorage.getItem("subcategoria").replaceAll(" ","_");
   let data = new FormData();
   data.append('codigo',cod);
   data.append('categoria',cat);
   data.append('subcategoria',subcat);
   fetch('prdSimilares.php',{
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
         })
   .then(res =>  res.json())
   .then(dataS => {
      console.log(dataS);      
   });
}
```

Esto es lo que tengo en prdSimilares.php:

```
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'] ?? null;
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'] ?? null;
$subcategoria = $_POST['subcategoria'] ?? null;

 public function obtener_productos_similares($codigo, $categoria, $subcategoria) {
            $db = new Connection();
            $query = "SELECT prod.id_producto, prod.descripcion_producto, cat.descripcion_categoria, suc.descripcion_subcategoria
                    FROM producto AS prod
                    INNER JOIN categoria AS cat
                        ON prod.id_categoria = cat.id_categoria
                    INNER JOIN subcategoria AS suc
                        ON prod.id_subcategoria = suc.id_subcategoria
                    WHERE prod.disponible = '1' AND prod.id_producto <> '$codigo' AND cat.descripcion_categoria = '$categoria' AND suc.descripcion_subcategoria = '$subcategoria'
                    ORDER BY prod.precio ASC";
            $resultado = $db->query($query);
            $datos = [];
            if ($resultado->num_rows > 1) {
                while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $datos[] = [
                        'codigo' => $row['id_producto'],
                        'nombre' => $row['descripcion_producto'],
                        'id_cat' => $row['id_categoria'],
                        'categoria' => $row['descripcion_categoria'],
                        'subcategoria' => $row['descripcion_subcategoria']
                    ];
                }
            }
            return $datos;
        }
```

En la tabla se están grabando varios ítems y a cada uno de estos les doy una categoría y una subcategoría; se están mostrando al principio todos los ítems que existen en esta tabla en un contenedor, también cada ítem tiene la opción de mostrar mayor información del mismo y aparte tengo un contenedor destinado a que se muestren los ítems de la categoría a la que pertenece el ítem seleccionado; ahora, el problema es que pueden haber uno o varios ítems que sean de esa misma categoría y mi problema es como no tengo certeza del número de ítems que va a haber en la tabla relacionados a dicha categoría y subcategoría debo hacer que en la consulta se graben los datos dependiendo del número filas (tuplas) devueltas.

Mi idea como ven es utilizar el `if($resultado->num_rows>=1) {...}` y seguido de esto poniendo la palabra reservada `else{}` (al no cumplirse la condición) grabar en el array los datos que tenga  la `$resultado`. Lo intenté de la siguiente manera:

```
else {
    $datos = $resultado;
}
return $datos;
```

Y en la consola me mostro vació pero en la tabla como al momento yo la estoy controlando se que existen tres ítems de una categoría / subcategoría por lo que me debería mostrar dos tuplas ya que en la consulta está especificado que sea diferente al código del ítem seleccionado `(AND prod.id_producto <> '$codigo')`.

Alguien tiene noción de lo que esta fallando y/o faltando para corregirlo y poder alcanzar el objetivo?

*RESUMEN*

Quiero saber cuantas filas o tuplas tengo en la consulta realizada para grabar los datos y luego mostrarlos en un contenedor.

lo que tengo:

```
function cargarSimilares() {
   let cod = localStorage.getItem("codPROD");
   let cat = localStorage.getItem("categoria");
   let subcat = localStorage.getItem("subcategoria").replaceAll(" ","_");
   let data = new FormData();
   data.append('codigo',cod);
   data.append('categoria',cat);
   data.append('subcategoria',subcat);
   fetch('prdSimilares.php',{
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
         })
   .then(res =>  res.json())
   .then(dataS => {
      console.log(dataS);      
   });
}
```

```
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'] ?? null;
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'] ?? null;
$subcategoria = $_POST['subcategoria'] ?? null;

 public function obtener_productos_similares($codigo, $categoria, $subcategoria) {
            $db = new Connection();
            $query = "SELECT prod.id_producto, prod.descripcion_producto, cat.descripcion_categoria, suc.descripcion_subcategoria
                    FROM producto AS prod
                    INNER JOIN categoria AS cat
                        ON prod.id_categoria = cat.id_categoria
                    INNER JOIN subcategoria AS suc
                        ON prod.id_subcategoria = suc.id_subcategoria
                    WHERE prod.disponible = '1' AND prod.id_producto <> '$codigo' AND cat.descripcion_categoria = '$categoria' AND suc.descripcion_subcategoria = '$subcategoria'
                    ORDER BY prod.precio ASC";
            $resultado = $db->query($query);
            $datos = [];
            if ($resultado->num_rows > 1) { 
                while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $datos[] = [
                        'codigo' => $row['id_producto'],
                        'nombre' => $row['descripcion_producto'],
                        'id_cat' => $row['id_categoria'],
                        'categoria' => $row['descripcion_categoria'],
                        'subcategoria' => $row['descripcion_subcategoria']
                    ];
                }
            }
            return $datos;
        }
```

a continuación del `if(){}` intente poniendo un else {}``:

```
else {
    //  cuando solo es una fila
    $datos[] = $resultado -> fetch_assoc();
}
```

no se mostró algún dato en consola (que lo puse para hacer las pruebas)

Comment: Ufff... no consigo entender qué quieres, y mira que me gustaría ayudarte. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo resumido de qué tienes, qué quieres, y qué no te funciona? Pero sencillito, como si no supiéramos qué estás haciendo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré una solución y fue cambiando en el llamado a la función y en la condicional le agregué el `isset()` a cada variable. El código en prdSimilares quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
    require "models/Producto.php";
    
    // $codigo = $_POST['codigo'] ?? null;
    // $categoria = $_POST['categoria'] ?? null;
    // $subcategoria = $_POST['subcategoria'] ?? null;

    if (isset($_POST['codigo']) && isset($_POST['categoria']) && isset($_POST['subcategoria'])) {
        $tabla_productos = new Producto();
        $similares = $tabla_productos->obtener_productos_similares($_POST['codigo'], $_POST['categoria'], $_POST['subcategoria']);
    } else {
        $similares = 0;
    }
    echo json_encode($similares);   
?>
```

El cambio básicamente se da en los argumentos que paso a la función.

Answer (score 0):

Pues da la sensación de que únicamente te falta llamar a la función que has creado en php y mostrar los datos con `json_encode()`. Algo así:

```
echo json_encode(
    obtener_productos_similares($codigo, $categoria, $subcategoria)
);
```

Prueba y me confirmas

Comment: Me envía ``[null]``; también intente poniendo el fetch en otro archivo ya que en el anterior la función se ejecutaba mediante un ``window.onload`` y en un mensaje me salío que no se podía ejecutar con ``window``

Comment: ¿Has probado si el fichero PHP te devuelve un JSON? Directamente, sin pasar por JS

Comment: No todavía, solo probé que la consulta este bien planteada en el mysql y si me devolvió los resultados que se esperaban. Ya voy a intentar con lo que me indicas